# Configuring a Canon MX360 scanner

Tags: linux, scanner

Since the system on one our computers has been changed from Windows to Linux I cannot work out how to scan from our Canon MX360. Can anyone explain how on Earth this is done? I did not install Linux, and I am not the main user of this computer, and find working out how to do some quite straightforward tasks really counteriniuitive. Please help, and do not use jargon, I am not that familiar with the relevant technical knowledge, and would appreciate a simple but clear explanation.

Comment: What distribution are you using? How is the scanner connected: USB?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I did find out how to do it in the end. It was simply a case with my not being familiar with where to find things like Simple Scan, and my father who is the main user of that computer was also unfamiliar with the relevant details; we are both used to Windows (Microsoft) but a friend and former colleague of Father's had installed Linux on this computer because he personally found it more useful. I personally find much of it very counterintuitive, but that is probably lack of familiarity with the different system. The printer/scanner is connected by USB.